# Wrong memory benchmarking results in Golang

Tags: go, testing, memory, benchmarking

I am using standard Golang benchmarking for my project.

Here are my PC and Golang Specs:

```
goos: windows
goarch: amd64
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz
go version:  go1.21.5
Available Memory: 64GB
```

After running the benchmark as follows:

```
go test -bench=MyCodeBench -benchtime=1x -timeout=120m -benchmem -run=^$
```

Note: I have to set the timeout to 120 minutes because the code takes so long to execute, and if I do not set the timeout flag, I will get the `*** Test killed with quit: ran too long` error.

Here is one of the benchmark results that I got:

```
MyCodeBench    1    776903113600 ns/op      402860098688 B/op       90982299 allocs/op
```

By converting memory allocation from B/op to GB/op, I will end up having **402GB** memory allocation!! I was wondering how it could be possible. I don't have that amount of memory on my PC.

PS: I thought maybe the memory allocation is incremental and it reports the whole memory allocation during the benchmark, which makes no sense, I need to know the current memory allocation for my code. Also, while running the code, I checked the memory usage using Windows task manager, it shows that only **23 GB** of memory has been used.

**Q1.** What can I do to get the correct benchmark results?

**Q2.** In addition, how can I get the memory throughput (MB/s)?

Regarding Q2, as it mentioned [here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.5:src/testing/benchmark.go):

```
// SetBytes records the number of bytes processed in a single operation.
// If this is called, the benchmark will report ns/op and MB/s.
func (b *B) SetBytes(n int64) { b.bytes = n }
```

by calling the function `SetBytes` and setting the `bytes`' number there should be MB/s in the results! however, I couldn't make that work.

Comment: It shows the total memory allocated, It does not show how much of that is freed. During the benchmark, most of that will be freed.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Thanks for your answer, how can I get the current memory allocation, not the total one, out of benchmarking?

Comment: Use `runtime.ReadMemStats`, however, in a runtime with GC, "current" memory usage does not mean much.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is the problem you're actually trying to solve? The purpose of benchmarking is to "stress" code paths, and understand how much resources they use per iteration. Benchmarks are less useful when you're doing 120 minutes of 1 iteration. I feel like suggesting profiling instead, but it's not clear what data you actually want.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Indeed, I am using the `runtime.ReadMemStats` now, but it also gives me [not pleasant] results. I mean I can see the actual memory usage through Task Manager.  Maybe, I am doing the wrong benchmarking as @coxley said.

Comment: @coxley Thanks for your answer. Actually, what I want is to get the maximum amount of memory that the required for function `f()` to be done. And running function `f()` will take a long time. In the end, I want it to have for example 2500.024MB memory usage only for function `f()`.

Comment: @Okay: Sounds like you want a trace profile — though the size of it might be unwieldy on a two hour function. There's a project `dominikh/gotraceui` that renders more efficiently than `go tool trace`, but unsure the boundaries. Note that the question you're trying to answer is tough in a function that escapes a lot to the heap — the number won't be reliable.

Comment: @coxley I'll check `gotraceui` to see if it works or not. I agree, results seem unreliable.